# Smartsheet API - copy and paste rows within the same sheet

Tags: python, copy, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

Is it possible to copy and paste rows within in a single sheet with smartsheet api?
I am using python.

When I try the following (using the same sheet id)

```
response = smartsheet_client.Sheets.copy_rows(
 <MySheetID>,
 smartsheet.models.CopyOrMoveRowDirective({
            'row_ids': [<MyRowID>],
            'to': smartsheet.models.CopyOrMoveRowDestination({
              'sheet_id': <MySheetID>
            })
          })
        )
```

I get the following error
"Cannot copy or move row(s) within the same sheet."

Answer (score 0):

Copy the rows to a temporary sheet and then copy them to the base sheet ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is that I lose the predecessor/dependency values when I copy to another sheet.